# Android positioning in pixels works but shouldn't

Tags: java, android, pixel

I've been positioning things (bitmaps, text) on a surface view using pixels. For example, to centre something I would take half of the width and height of the rectangle representing the screen.  Screen width and height are being returned as expected.  My phone (480*800) is reporting the available screen as 442*800, with density 1.5, and running on a 240*320 emulator the available screen is reported as 221*320, density 0.75.  All as expected.

But these values, surely, are pixels, and so surely to centre something I should first multiply by the density factor before halving.  The strange thing is everything is centred perfectly, on both the low res emulator and my high res phone.  This doesn't make sense to me.

On both screens, in order to get text to appear the same, I set the size using a density scaled value, as I'd expect, and this works.

In the manifest I've declared support for all screen sizes (although I was seeing the same 'correct' behaviour before I did this as well)

Why are the pixel values 'working' without me adjusting them for density? I'm now very confused.

Answer (score 3):

A pixel is a pixel is a pixel!

It is the lowest common denominator of screens and sizes.

Density is how many pixels are packed into a unit of measure, typically an inch. on a physical display.

For example, taking a physical width of 5 inches, with a resolution of 500x1000 yields a density of 200dpi (1000 pixels in 5 inches).  A physical width of 4 inches with the same resolution yields a density of 250dpi (1000 pixels in 4 inches).

x=500 (half the width) is the centre of the screen on both and is independent of density.  Indeed, half the width in pixels is the centre of the screen for any size screen at any density.

Comment: I don't disagree with that. My point is that positions are specified in dps, or rather, they are not as evidence would suggest.   Are you effectively saying that coordinates of rectangles etc. etc. etc. should be given in pixels?  And doesn't this make it difficult to write code which will position things sensibly on different devices?

Comment: I might be confused.  You started by saying "I've been positioning things (bitmaps, text) on a surface view using pixels."  I assumed that you are using raw pixels to position things, which is fine if you are measuring the device and doing the maths.  Or have I missed the point entirely?  Remember that DIP (or DP) and DPI are completely different things and are not pixels (despite the name DIP - it's a ratio).

Comment: I have been using raw pixels and everything has been fine,but then it occured to me that it "shouldn't" be working (although clearly it is, hence my confusion).But, I think I've got it now.The system expects coordinates in pixels (naturally).If I want something to be in the middle of the screen plus "a bit", then to make that "bit" look "the same" on different resolution screens  I need to adjust the "bit" for density before adding it to the pixel position of the centre which clearly must remain untouched. As is often the case, saying things aloud (writing in this case) makes the penny drop.

Comment: Spot on.  So half the width in pixels gives you the middle of your circle but if you then subtracted 50 pixels (to make the left of the ball correct), then your ball size will be all over the place.  Scaling the offset is the way to go.  Glad the penny dropped (I remember spending days in one app when I first had to solve this ;).  Cheers

Comment: I should have slept on it or tried talking it through with a cheeseplant or something first.  Many thanks...